# How to marshal an integer value to hexadecimal using go-yaml?

Tags: go, yaml

I have a structure with integer fields, the representation of which makes sense to humans in hexadecimal form. For example, let this be the *Vendor ID* field.

I want to save this data to a YAML file for manual editing and then load it from the file. As I understand it, there are no problems with hexadecimal representation of numbers in YAML itself, but `go-yaml` (I use `v3`) encodes integers in decimal form and I have not found a normal way to make it save them in hexadecimal form.

Let's take the following code as a starting point:

```golang
import (
    //...
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type DeviceInfo struct {
    VendorId uint32 `yaml:"vendorid"`
}

func main() {
    deviceInfo := DeviceInfo{VendorId: 0xdeadbeef}

    yml, err := yaml.Marshal(deviceInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(yml))
}
```

This code generates YAML with a decimal value:

```yaml
vendorid: 3735928559
```

Next, `go-yaml` allows you to create a [custom marshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Marshaler) for your own types. I did this (I deliberately omitted the `0x` prefix in the `fmt.Sprintf()` format string):

```golang
type Uint32Hex uint32

func (U Uint32Hex) MarshalYAML() (interface{}, error) {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", U), nil
}

type DeviceInfo struct {
    VendorId Uint32Hex `yaml:"vendorid"`
}

func main() {
    // the same code
}
```

This code generates the value in hexadecimal, but without the `0x` prefix (logical for now):

```yaml
vendorid: deadbeef
```

But if I add the `0x` prefix in the custom marshaler:

```golang
func (U Uint32Hex) MarshalYAML() (interface{}, error) {
    return fmt.Sprintf("0x%x", U), nil
}
```

The value is generated correctly, but not as a number, but as a string:

```yaml
vendorid: "0xdeadbeef"
```

And in order to then unmarshal this line into a number, I will also have to write a custom unmarshaler. I don't like this solution.

In the end, I have the following questions:

1. Is there any simple way to generate hexadecimal numbers using `go-yaml` that I haven't found?
2. Is it possible to make a custom encoder in terms of `go-yaml` as an extension of the package without changing the package itself? For me, a more convenient way would be to pass a format tag in the structure description, for example, like this:

   ```golang
   type DeviceInfo struct {
       VendorId uint32 `yaml:"vendorid,hex"`
   }
   ```
3. If this requires changing the package code, what is the Go practice for such cases? Just copy the package files into my project, modify as needed and import it locally?

Comment: maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54584832/how-to-deal-with-hex-values-in-yaml-using-both-go-and-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that quoting strings is optional in yaml, but `go-yaml` uses the same the same internal architecture as the JSON encoder. This means that custom marshaling is processed first and then, entirely separately, quoting logic is applied. The reason `deadbeef` isn't quoted, but `0xdeadbeef` is, is because the latter *is a number*. It gets quoted so that it's not accidentally unmarshalled as a number when it knows it should be a string, because your custom marshaler returned a string. Because `deadbeef` can't be read as a valid number, it doesn't need to be quoted. There are two things you can do:

1. Complete your custom Marshal/Unmarshal from string:

```golang
func (U *Uint32Hex) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    parsed, err := strconv.ParseUint(value.Value, 0, 32)
    *U = Uint32Hex(parsed)
    return err
}
```

2. Fork `go-yaml` and modify it. If you do this, you shouldn't change the import in your source files. Instead, you should add a `replace` directive to your `go.mod`, like this:

```golang
require gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1

replace gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 => ../yaml.v3 // Your local path to the fork
```

I prefer solution 1, because it allows you serialize these values in your preferred way, without diverging from the yaml that others produce, and doesn't require you to maintain a fork.